"The destination CIDR block 192.168.9.0/27 is equal to or more specific than one of this VPC's CIDR blocks. This route can target only an intrface or
I have two other templates. This template is taking imports from another template and I can share them if need be. I am working on a project with a tight deadline and I am trying to get this done. Any suggestions or feedback would be great
Im getting this error and I am honestly not sure why. Can anyone help me with this?
The other 2 templates. One is a Transit Gateway, The Other has VPCS, Internet Gateway, some routes to IG, Subnets and Route Tables. I will share those templates if is needed.
Here is the code with the routes and a few Transit Gateway Routes for the Transit Gateway Attachments.
Any questions please ask
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Template for a startup company looking to move their services to the cloud",
    "Parameters": {
        "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for Transit Gateway",
            "Default": "192.168.7.0/24"
        },
        "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR2": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for Transit Gateway",
            "Default": "192.168.5.0/24"
        },
        "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR3": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for Transit Gateway",
            "Default": "192.168.9.0/24"
        },
        "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR4": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for Transit Gateway",
            "Default": "192.168.8.0/24"
        },
        "PrivateRoute1": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for the private subnets to communicate",
            "Default": "192.168.7.0/24"
        },
        "PrivateRoute2": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for the pribate subnets to communicate with one another",
            "Default": "192.168.5.0/24"
        },
        "RoutingDomainPrivateRoute": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for the private subnets to communicate",
            "Default": "192.168.9.0/24"
        },
        "RoutingDomainPrivateRoute2": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Route for the pribate subnets to communicate with one another",
            "Default": "192.168.8.0/24"
        },
        "RoutingDomainStackName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Stack name for the template with VPC and other resources",
            "Default": "RoutingDomain"
        },
        "TransitGatewayStackName" : {
            "Type" : "String",
            "Description" : "Stack name for the template with the Transit Gateway",
            "Default" : "TransitGateway"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "PrivateRoute1A": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableID"
                    }
                },
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "PrivateRoute1"
                },
                "GatewayId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${TransitGatewayStackName}-TransitGatewayID"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "PrivateRoute2A": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableIDB"
                    }
                },
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "PrivateRoute2"
                },
                "GatewayId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${TransitGatewayStackName}-TransitGatewayID"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "RDPrivateRoute1": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableIDC"
                    }
                },
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "RoutingDomainPrivateRoute"
                },
                "GatewayId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${TransitGatewayStackName}-TransitGatewayID"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "RDPrivateRoute2": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableIDD"
                    }
                },
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "RoutingDomainPrivateRoute2"
                },
                "GatewayId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${TransitGatewayStackName}-TransitGatewayID"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "TransitGatewayRoute": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute",
            "Properties": {
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR"
                },
                "TransitGatewayAttachmentId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-TransitGatewayAttachmentID"
                    }
                },
                "TransitGatewayRouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableID1"
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        },
        "TransitGatewayRoute2": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute",
            "Properties": {
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR2"
                },
                "TransitGatewayAttachmentId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-TransitGatewayAttachmentIDb"
                    }
                },
                "TransitGatewayRouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableID2"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "TransitGatewayRoute3": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute",
            "Properties": {
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR3"
                },
                "TransitGatewayAttachmentId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-TransitGatewayAttachmentIDc"
                    }
                },
                "TransitGatewayRouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableID1"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "TransitGatewayRoute4": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute",
            "Properties": {
                "DestinationCidrBlock": {
                    "Ref": "TransitGatewayRouteCIDR4"
                },
                "TransitGatewayAttachmentId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-TransitGatewayAttachmentIDd"
                    }
                },
                "TransitGatewayRouteTableId": {
                    "Fn::ImportValue": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${RoutingDomainStackName}-RouteTableID2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


For any X, the netmask X/24 catches the same IPs as the netmask X/25. If you use these e.g. for routing, X/25 will not make any difference. Maybe you got the order of them wrong?

what do you mean  any x? im not sure what you are trying to say

It's saying that a CIDR of 192.168.9.0/27 is 'inside' a CIDR of 192.168.9.0/24. However, I can't see where the /27 address is referenced in your template. Do you know where it's getting the /27 CIDR from?

this template is importing values from another template is all i can think of. let me try to redeploy and see what it says

tried to redeploy and got the same error except it said 192.168.9.0./24. Im not sure what the issue is. Any suggestions?
